# Ubuntu 12.10 - how to set the resolution to 1024x768 and correct rate? using command line when ever system starts

Tags: 12.10, xorg, display, x11, vga

I have this following code where my VGA output is always showing out of range. How can i resolve it?

```
$ cvt 1024 768
$ xrandr --newmode shvga 74.50 1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798
$ xrandr --addmode VGA-1 shvga
$ xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode shvga
```

i also applied xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode shvga --rate 60 or 70 but none is helping. Any permanent solution?

**Follow up:** (reference: http://grenage.com/xorg.html)

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/xorg-conf-custom-screen-resolution-444052/

Comment: @ToDo: OK it works, see my follow up. Where i needed one screen 1024x768 on VGA, and HDMI 720p both is working with above setting.

Comment: Please write this up as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GT 620 (rev a1)
$ apt-get install xresprobe
$ sudo ddcprobe
vbe: VESA 3.0 detected.
oem: NVIDIA
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
product: GF108 Board - 1071v008 Chip Rev
memory: 14336kb
mode: 640x400x256
mode: 640x480x256
mode: 800x600x16
mode: 800x600x256
mode: 1024x768x16
mode: 1024x768x256
mode: 1280x1024x16
mode: 1280x1024x256
mode: 320x200x64k
mode: 320x200x16m
mode: 640x480x64k
mode: 640x480x16m
mode: 800x600x64k
mode: 800x600x16m
mode: 1024x768x64k
mode: 1024x768x16m
mode: 1280x1024x64k
mode: 1280x1024x16m
edid: 
edidfail

$ gtf 1024 768 60
  # 1024x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 64.11 MHz
  Modeline "1024x768_60.00"  64.11  1024 1080 1184 1344  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync

$ vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    ModelName "GF108"
    HorizSync 24 - 82
    VertRefresh 50 - 75
# 1024x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 64.11 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_60.00"  64.11  1024 1080 1184 1344  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "nv"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device "Device0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

On other hand i have another screen

```
    echo "[resolution]: trying 720p"
    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && cvt 1280 720 70
    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr --newmode legend 74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748
    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 legend
    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode legend
    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 legend
    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode legend
```

Which gives me:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2304 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   1024x768       75.0 +   70.1     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0 +   50.0  
   1920x1080      50.0     60.0     25.0     30.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1680x945       60.0  
   1400x1050      74.9     59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1280x800       74.9     59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x768       74.9     60.0  
   1440x576       25.0  
   1440x480       30.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   848x480        60.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0     59.9  
   legend         59.9* 
VGA-1 connected 1024x768+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 228mm
   1024x768       60.0*+   75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```